# How can I set a layout to a tab in QTabWidget?

Tags: c++, qt, qlayout

I have created a `QTabWidget` (with no tabs) using the **Qt Design** tool, and now I need to create tabs and add widgets dynamically.

I can create the tab and add the widget using the following code:

```
MyCustomWidget *myCustomWidget = new MyCustomWidget(this);
ui->myTabWidget->addTab(myCustomWidget, "New Tab");
```

The problem is that the widget stays in the top left corner of my `QTabWidget` but I need to align it in the center (horizontally) of my `QTabWidget`.

How can I set a horizontal layout to this new tab created?

**Note 1**: My widget (`MyCustomWidget`) has a fixed size.

**Note 2**: I'm using Qt 5.3.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following @Satus idea, I create a new `QFrame`, set the minimum size as the size of **myTabWidget**, set a horizontal layout and add **myCustomWidget** inside it, adding two `QSpacerItem` (left and right):

```
QFrame *frame= new QFrame(this);
frame->setMinimumWidth(ui->myTabWidget->width());
frame->setMinimumHeight(ui->myTabWidget->height());

MyCustomWidget *myCustomWidget = new MyCustomWidget(frame);

QHBoxLayout *hLayout = new QHBoxLayout();

hLayout->addItem(new QSpacerItem(10, 10, QSizePolicy::Expanding, QSizePolicy::Expanding));
hLayout->addWidget(myCustomWidget);
hLayout->addItem(new QSpacerItem(10, 10, QSizePolicy::Expanding, QSizePolicy::Expanding));

frame->setLayout(hLayout);

ui->myTabWidget->addTab(frame, "New Tab");
```

It worked, but if someone has a more elegant way to do so, please share with us.

Answer (score 8):

You can use QT designer.
Select QTabWidget and have the Tab that needs its layout changed to visible (and it has to contain elements e.g. QLabel, etc..)
Select the QTabWidget-> Right-click->Layout->Layout vertically
The problem is that it is more intuitive to do it on the Qwidget while you have to do it on the QTabWidget

Comment: Thanks so much. That was driving me crazy trying to add the layout to the widget. The design of Qt Designer is infuriatingly bad.

Comment: This is the correct answer. Make sure the tab you want to apply the layout to is the currently opened tab, then select the QTabWidget object, right click, and you can set the layout. You can even apply different layouts to different tabs this way.

Answer (score 2):

It will always be in the top left corner. You can either add another widget on top of yours and them put your widget in the middle of that widget, or make your widget the size of the tab and position its content in the middle. You can use `setLayout` method of QWidget to set your widget layout.

Answer (score 2):

You do not need a QFrame, a simple QWidget and a centered layout will do it :

```
auto w = new QWidget;

auto txtEdit = new QTextEdit; // Replace with whatever custom widget
txtEdit->setFixedSize(150, 150); // Only here to simulate your fixed size

auto layout = new QVBoxLayout;
layout->addWidget(txtEdit, 0, Qt::AlignHCenter);
w->setLayout(layout);

ui->tabWidget->addTab(w, "MyTab");
```

Answer (score 1):

I use QT Creator 4.7.0 Based on QT 5.11.1.
I can't change the layout of a tab of QTabWidget using QT designer. The all items from Lay out are disabled. I am very strange. Only method I solve this problem is to edit ui file(in my case, mainwindow.ui file).
From:

```
<widget class="QWidget" name="tab_3">
<attribute name="title">
<string>Insert Object</string>
</attribute>
</widget>
```

To:

```
<widget class="QWidget" name="tab_3">
<attribute name="title">
<string>Insert Object</string>
</attribute>
<layout class="QVBoxLayout" name="verticalLayout">
</layout>
</widget>
```

As result, the layout of tab of QTabWidget have changed.
Thanks.